# Would the curvature of a submanifold affect the curvature of the space around it?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

There was research article that showed that gravitational waves and electromagnetic waves loosing energy by the inverse square law. The researchers concluded that, since gravitational waves obey the inverse square law, extra-dimensions don't exist.

Since gravity is the intrinsic curvature, why would the curvature of a submanifold affect the curvature of the extra dimensions. For example, a sphere embedded in a euclidean space. The sphere is curved, yet the space around it is flat.

Comment: Well, the Nash-Kuiper theorem says that if $(M^n,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, there exists a sufficiently large $N$ such that there exists an isometric embedding $(M,g) \hookrightarrow (\mathbb{R}^N,\mathrm{eucl})$. In particular, the local geometry of $M$ has no effect on the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^N$: $M$ may be as curved as requested, it is a submanifold of a flat space. There may be some general relativity results, or physical assumptions, that are hidden behind the reasoning.